# How to create a map layer from a map file?

Tags: mapserver, mapfile

I am new to MapServer, I want to create map layer; is it required to use a shapefile  for this, and if so how can I use it.

Map file (eg2.map) is given below

```
MAP 
    NAME ENG1 
    STATUS ON 
    SIZE 800 500 
    IMAGETYPE GIF 
    IMAGECOLOR 240 240 240 
    SHAPEPATH "/www/geog5870/geog5870test/data" 
    EXTENT 87000 8000 660000 660000 
    UNITS METERS 
    WEB 
        IMAGEPATH "/www/tmp/" 
        IMAGEURL "/tmp/" 
    END 
    LAYER 
        NAME "EnglishGOR" 
        TYPE POLYGON 
        STATUS DEFAULT 
        DATA "England_gor_2001_area" 
        CLASS 
           NAME "English Government Office Regions" 
           OUTLINECOLOR 60 60 60 
           COLOR 255 255 0 
           SYMBOL 0 
        END 
    END 
END
```

Comment: http://mapserver.org/tutorial/index.html

Have you checked the tutorial page?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, no it is not required to use a shapefile as a data source to create a map using MapServer, this is just one possible option.

As has been pointed out in comments, the MapServer site provides [documentation](http://mapserver.org/tutorial/index.html) on how to configure a map file to create maps.

If you want to see a shapefile specific example you could try the OneGeology [WMS cookbook](http://onegeology.org/wmsCookbook/home.html) tutorial